# Places in Android doesn't show suggestions in the release APK

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using Places to get suggestions for the user when he searches something in the searchbar.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
    String key = "key=" + context.getString(R.string.google_maps_key);

    String input="";

    try {
        input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        DLog.d(e);
    }

    // place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    String language = "language=it";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key + "&" + language;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
    try{
        // Fetching the data from we service
        data = downloadUrl(url);
```

There is other code, but I think that this is the needed part. However, it works pretty good when I launch it from Android Studio, but it totally not work when I install the signed APK.

I had the same problem with the map (that keeps to be blank) but after putting my SHA1 key and the package name in the Google Console API, it works fine. But places still doesn't.

Any idea of the reason why it works that way? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you need to add both the SHA1 of the debug key and of the release key in the Google Console.

I used:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/fil/.android/debug.keystore
```

From the platform-tools foulder of the android_sdk (although, I'm in a Mac, in Linux it might be different) to get the debug key. Then, the same but with the release key.

After that, I insert both the SHA1;package as "Key for Android applications" in the APIs & Auth foulder.

I've also created a server key for places specifically.

Comment: I have a application which uses places web services. For which I have a server key. But on release apk which i download from market (alpha testing) and it doesn't work at all. If I use a server key then I do not see place to add SHA1 key. ??  Any idea how to solve this issue ??